# Spring Boot OAuth2 SSO

Tags: spring, security, oauth, spring-boot

I'm not an expert in Spring Security..
I have one single angularjs app, which has OAuth2 based authentication and authorization.
Now I need to add additional app, but users and passwords should be the same for both apps.
So.. I need to have one sso server and two resource servers.
I want to implement that with modern spring boot.
Currently I authenticate users against /oauth/token with grant_type=password
I wonder if there are some samples of SSO and Resource servers that would allow me to authenticate users against http://sso.host/oauth/token?username=someuser&password=somepass&grant_type=password
so.. I will get my acccess and refresh tokens as the result of success authentication.
And access token would be good to use against http://resource.host/rest/someresource
while refresh token would be good to get access_tokens at http://sso.host/oauth/token?grant_type=refresh

I don't want my apps to be redirected to any urls..
I don't need any login forms, just json responses.

Here is my current spting-security-oauth.xml config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2-2.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd "><beans>

<authorization-server client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" token-services-ref="tokenServices" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2">
    <refresh-token />
    <client-credentials />
    <password authentication-manager-ref="userAuthenticationManager" disabled="false"/>
</authorization-server>

<authentication-manager id="clientAuthenticationManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService" />
</authentication-manager>

<authentication-manager alias="userAuthenticationManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
            <user name="username" password="password" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless" authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
    <anonymous enabled="false" />
    <http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
    <custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" before="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</http>

<oauth:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter" resource-id="rest_server" token-services-ref="tokenServices" />

<oauth:client-details-service id="clientDetails">
    <oauth:client client-id="the_client" secret="" scope="read,write" authorized-grant-types="password,refresh_token,client_credentials" authorities="ROLE_USER"/>
</oauth:client-details-service>


<http pattern="/rest/**" create-session="never" entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint" access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <anonymous enabled="false" />

    <intercept-url pattern="/rest/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</http>

<bean id="tokenStore" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.InMemoryTokenStore" />

<bean id="tokenServices" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
    <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
    <property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true" />
    <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails" />
    <property name="accessTokenValiditySeconds" value="300" />
    <property name="refreshTokenValiditySeconds" value="3600" />
</bean>

<bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.vote.ScopeVoter" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter" />
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="realmName" value="test" />
</bean>

<bean id="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="realmName" value="theRealm/client" />
    <property name="typeName" value="Basic" />
</bean>

<bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="clientAuthenticationManager" />
</bean>

<bean id="clientDetailsUserService" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
    <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails" />
</bean>

<bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler" />

<sec:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-class="true">
    <sec:expression-handler ref="oauthExpressionHandler" />
</sec:global-method-security>

<oauth:expression-handler id="oauthExpressionHandler" />
<oauth:web-expression-handler id="oauthWebExpressionHandler" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can naturally do SSO with the password grant type. You're probably best with the authorization code flow. Oauth2 sso happens because both client apps check for the authenticated session on the authorization server and,  if one has already logged in, the second app doesn't need to provide credentials again. 
https://spring.io/blog/2015/02/03/sso-with-oauth2-angular-js-and-spring-security-part-v is a good example with angularjs and spring boot.

That is, if you want SSO, I think you'll need redirection to the authorization server for initial login.